# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate bundle manifest

Tags: java, eclipse

How to resolve this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate bundle manifest: 
org.eclipse.cdt.ui_5.5.0.201302132326.jar Stack trace : 

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate bundle manifest:
file:/local/mnt/workspace/chenna/eclipse2/Hexagon_SDK/2.0/tools/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.ui_5.5.0.201302132326.jar
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.utils.Utils.getManifestMainAttributes(Utils.java:208)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.utils.Utils.getClausesManifestMainAttributes(Utils.java:202)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxBundlesState.isSystemBundle(EquinoxBundlesState.java:150)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxBundlesState.composeState(EquinoxBundlesState.java:339)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxBundlesState.composeNewState(EquinoxBundlesState.java:290)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxBundlesState.<init>(EquinoxBundlesState.java:260)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxManipulatorImpl.getBundlesState(EquinoxManipulatorImpl.java:145)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxManipulatorImpl.save(EquinoxManipulatorImpl.java:366)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.LazyManipulator.save(LazyManipulator.java:97)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.EclipseTouchpoint.saveManipulator(EclipseTouchpoint.java:61)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.EclipseTouchpoint.commit(EclipseTouchpoint.java:137)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.EngineSession.commit(EngineSession.java:123)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:93)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:44)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:41)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:23)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director.app.DirectorApplication.executePlan(DirectorApplication.java:767)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director.app.DirectorApplication.planAndExecute(DirectorApplication.java:760)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director.app.DirectorApplication.performProvisioningActions(DirectorApplication.java:747)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director.app.DirectorApplication.run(DirectorApplication.java:1040)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director.app.DirectorApplication.start(DirectorApplication.java:1222)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)    at
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)   at
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)   at
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

The above error was caused by 
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)

I dont know the root cause of this error. but reinstalling eclipse solves this issue ? any idea how reinstallng eclipse solved this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason finally, org.eclipse.cdt.ui_5.5.0.201302132326.jar has downloaded partially. Reinstalling eclipse solves the issue